# Azure VIrtual Machine Reservation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have deployed one web app with azure Virtual machine. Now I want to reserve Virtual Machine for one year. Is it Possible in India to reserve a windows server virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to buy reserved instances in India.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible, but I would recommend you must use auto shut shown option to reduce your cost. and Pricing option you can refer the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

Azure reserved instances is not supported in India region yet. If your account is from India and want to buy azure vm anywhere it does jot support it yet